# no consistent connection when using RBP as Ethernet gadget on macos

Tags: usb, ssh, macos, gadget

I am trying to connect my RBP to my MacBook using Ethernet gadget.
I followed this guide [link](https://learn.adafruit.com/turning-your-raspberry-pi-zero-into-a-usb-gadget/ethernet-gadget), I also had to share internet to the `RNDIS/Ethernet Gadget`.

I managed to SSH to my RBP and to access Internet from my RBP. 
The issue is that, after 2 minutes the connection drops and I have to unplug and plug my RBP to access again to it.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Are you able to test from another device? Particularly one running Windows or Linux?